# Tanh version of a Fourier Transform?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, reference-request

I am trying to perform some computations in an environment where it is much easier to compute the hyperbolic tangent function (tanh) than cosines or sines.  This prevents me from performing Fourier transforms.  With that limitation in mind, I am interested in the behavior of the following transform:

Given an $L_2$-integrable function $f:R\rightarrow R$, define

$$\overline{f}(a,b)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tanh(ax+b) f(x) dx$$

My questions are:

(1) Does anyone recognize this transform?

(2) Can we recover $f$ if we are given $\overline{f}(a,b)$ for all $a,b$?

(3) Can we recover $f$ if we are given $\overline{f}(1,b)$ for all $b$?

(4) Is there a counterpart to the "variable addition trick" for the discrete Fourier transform?  Let me describe what I have in mind.

In an applied setting, the discrete Fourier transform provides an efficient tool for computing the distribution of the sum of two random variables.  The technique works as follows: assume we have random variables $X, Y$ and respective pdfs $f,g$.  We wish to estimate the pdf of $X+Y$, which we will call $h$.  Since $h$ is the convolution of $f$ and $g$, we can compute it with the Fourier transform: 
$$h=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(f)\mathcal{F}(g))$$

If we wish to do this in practice, we approximate $f$ and $g$ by a finite set of (say) $N$ equally spaced points.  Naively, computing the convolution would take $O(N^2)$ steps, but by using the fast Fourier transform algorithm and the argument above, we can approximately compute $h$ in $O(N \log(N))$ steps.  Because one frequently wants to analyze $X+Y$ and the computational speed-up is so dramatic, this trick gets used a lot.

My question is: suppose I try the same trick with the tanh() transform.  If I indicate the transform by $\mathcal{T}$, suppose I compute:
$$h=\mathcal{T}^{-1}(\mathcal{T}(f)\mathcal{T}(g))$$
What is $h$?  Does it have a simpler interpretation in terms of $f$ and $g$ (like "convolution")?  Better still, does it have a simpler interpretation in terms of $X$ and $Y$ (like "addition")?  Is it even a pdf?  (Thanks to Terry Tao's comment on #3 above, we can see that $\mathcal{T}^{-1}$ exists, but is only defined up to a constant; let us assume we set the constant so that $\int h=1$.)

Comment: Is the integral understood as a principal value?
If yes, can you prove that $\int| \overline{f}(a, b)|^2 db < \infty$ for some $a$
or $\int| \overline{f}(a, b)|^2 da < \infty$ for some $b$? 

Comment: It looks like an attenuated (or weighted) X-ray transform.

Comment: Yes. I don't have a reference for the inversion formula for the X-ray transform, but one should be able to follow the procedure for the Radon transform given here:

http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/num/inst/natterer/Preprints/2000/natterer/paper.pdf

Comment: It seems rather ambitious to expect an inverse for a map from functions in one variable to functions in 2 variables.

Comment: It doesn't look that ambitious to look for an inverse if you have an injective map and want to compute the antecedent of an element which is known to be in the image!

Comment: I guess $a$ and $b$ are real? Have you already exploited a series expansion $e^{\pm 2(ax\pm b)}$ for $\tanh$. Then this becomes essentially a question, which is equivalent to recover a probability distribution in terms of moment sums, from something like $2 +2 \sum_{n>0}EX^n e^{bn}$, which is holomorph in $b$ and where $EX^n$ is the $n$ th moment of your distribution. So in principle you can recover the moments $EX^n$, which is sufficient for the distribution of $X$, if it is distributed with total mass $1$. So $(3)$ yes!

Comment: Indeed, $\overline{f}(a,b)$ is essentially the Radon transform of the two-variable function $f(x) \tanh(y)$, so the inverse Radon transform will do the trick.  If one is only given $\overline{f}(1,b)$, this is essentially a convolution of f with the distribution $\tanh$, so a Fourier transform should be able to perform deconvolution as long as one avoids frequencies where the Fourier transform of $\tanh$ (or its derivative $\sech^2$, which is integrable) vanishes. 

Comment: To Carnahan: In case the intention wasn't clear, I've restated the problem in (3) and (4).

To pm:  That approach sounds really interesting, but I'm getting confused on a few elementary points.  How exactly are you getting the $2+2\sum_{n>0} EX^ne^{bn}$ expansion (since that doesn't look like the Taylor expansion of tanh).  Also, given a linear combination of moments, is it in general possible to recover the original distribution uniquely?  (And I guess in practice I would recover the distribution by sampling a finite set of points and using a semi-definite program?)

  Thanks,
  Bill

Comment: So, I guess (2)-(3) are satisfactory answered, and for (1) you have the comment by Terry Tao. But for (4), I can only speak for myself, but I actually do not understand what you want here... Can you give the example for the construction of adding random variables with the Fourier transform explicitely?

Comment: Sorry, I did not directly see the question in your comment and my previous comment was also partly wrong. You are not getting moments, but exponential moments. First, $tanh(z) = 1-2 (1+ e^{2z})^{-1} = 1 + 2\sum\limits_{n>0} (-e^{2z})^n$ for $z<0$ and similarly for $x>0$. Then plugin $z=b+x$ and integrate summand for summand. So you get some Fourier expansion $\sum\limits_{n>0} a_n e^{bn}$ for $b<0$. Since $a_n$ is essentially the Laplace transform of $f$ at $n$, and I know at least that the question to recover $f$ from exponential moments should be discussed in the standard books.

Comment: Dear pm,  Thanks so much for the clarification of your exponential moment suggestion, I understand now.  I hadn't explained #4 very clearly; I've taken another stab at it above.  I am somewhat tempted to split this part off as a separate question.